# remove bar title of application from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

i would like to remove title bar on applications [blue bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04iHF.png) in android studio,i've tried using a different theme in manifest.xml
( `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar"`) but this didn't work, then, how i do to hide this title bar from this activity?

[image: activity.xml]

my manifest.xml is this:

[image: manifest.xml]

and my styles.xml is this:

[image]

Comment: In the preview there this theme options drop down where you can select which theme to use, there you can select the No title bar theme

Comment: where i can find this option? thank you for reply!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left side above the phone( layout preview ) there AppTheme text click on that and choose the theme that you want. I've highlighted it with red[image]

Comment: ok, i found , and chose no title bar. but return me that missing style

Answer (score 0):

Go to App>Res>Values>styles xml.

The first thing that you have after the `<resources>` tag is another `<style>` tag with the name `AppTheme` probably? Or something similar. If you're using a `Material theme`, you'd have the `colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark` and `accentColor` declared there.

After the end of the `</style>` tag for this theme, create a new one with the same name but add `.NoActionBar` to the name, like that:

```
    <style name="YourThemeName.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
```

Now go to your `Manifest.xml` and in each `<activity>` tag there probably is a theme attribute. Change it so that the activity you want to not have a title bar uses the new theme we created:

```
 android:theme="@style/YourThemeName.NoActionBar"
```

**How your theme should look like**:

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/tealDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple700</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/teal</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Just **remember** to change the color names to the ones you have declared in your colors.xml . Now in your Manifest, the Theme for your app should be `MyTheme` and the theme for each `Activity` not using a Title bar should be `MyTheme.NoActionBar`

Comment: so, i went to my styles.xml and i found this:
      '<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">...'
i've tried to add my style for NoTitleBar, after i've changed in my manifest, but nothing, display of devise show me Android. Cordination layout.

Comment: In the manifest, in each <activity> tag (not the application tag), make sure this particular theme is used and not just AppTheme. I added more info in my answer, make sure it's all like that. If what you have doesn't work, try copy pasting my code and setting the theme as I instructed, is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

this is my Stiles.xml

```
<resources>>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

and for my activity manifest.xml i do this:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />



</application>
```

Comment: When adding more information about your question, don't post an answer unless it's an answer, just edit your original post. I don't know if you copy-pasted incorrectly but obviously your starting tag has a double `>>` The file should start with  <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">  and end with  </resources>

Comment: And by the way, you don't even have a proper theme setup. That's why I gave you code how it should look like. You define the colorPrimary etc and you extend one of the AppCompat themes. Look at my answer and copy the styles after "How your theme should look like"

Comment: sorry i started from few days to see android language, so if i add <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> to styles.xml say me that don't found a file, i don't understand this code sorry!

Comment: Check this video out to see how to download the support libraries if you don't have them yet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkxGbOrgCzs And this is a video about themes and styles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXpG3Xq0w3A at 8:15 they start talking about app themes

Comment: thank iBobb, now i see this videos and i hope this help me!! thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the latest version of Android for your app. If not please mention the version of Android that is being used. Following is the way in which you can remove the blue bar on the top of the activity:-

1. Go to the activity xml file and remove the following code from the xml:-

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
   ```

Now if you switch to the design mode then you will be able to see the screen without the blue bar on the top.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't find this, in which xml?

Comment: Can you paste the activity xml for your screen where you are trying to remove the blue bar ?

Comment: i add  it in the question !

Comment: Can you try removing the line "app:layout" from the LinearLayout tag of your activity xml ?

Comment: linear:layout must have android:layout, if i erase it return me an error then missing